# Nuxt 3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not define

Tags: nuxtjs3

Nuxt3 project

npm run build

npm run start

```
Nuxi 3.0.0                                                                                                     15:16:13
ℹ Node.js version: 14.21.2                                                                                     15:16:13
ℹ Preset: node-server                                                                                          15:16:13
ℹ Working dir: .output                                                                                         15:16:13
ℹ Loading .env. This will not be loaded when running the server in production.                                 15:16:13
ℹ Starting preview command: node ./server/index.mjs                                                            15:16:13
                                                                                                               15:16:13
Listening http://[::]:3000
```

http://localhost:3000/

then got error in browser

```
entry.042ab8e0.js:19 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at entry.042ab8e0.js:19:3018
```

upgrade my node 14 to 18 then still got the same error

Comment: Why are you even using `require`? Use `import` in a client-side context.

Comment: It auto-generated file "entry.042ab8e0.js" inside dist folder, when I run npm build

"let UUID=require("ordered-uuid")" 
this is the line that caused error on when I run npm start

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: `ordered-uuid` library is designed to be used by a "traditional"  Node backend and not for frontend.

Longer answer: `require` is something coming from `CommonJS`, which is what NodeJs uses. It was used as a way to dynamically import modules. However since the introduction to JavaScript Modules in ES6 (aka JS 2015 aka ECMAScript 2015, aka ECMAScript 6) `import` and `export` are the new standard of doing things. Also Nuxt follows ES

`require` is not recognised by ES6 and thus the reason why you get this error. Since `ordered-uuid` hasn't been updated in the last 6 years. I suggest you to find something that suits your needs more. For example: https://github.com/danielboven/ordered-uuid-v4

> `npm install ordered-uuid-v4`

This library has both a CommonJS compatible approach as well as a ES6 compatible approach.

---

Nuxt actually has a nice page explainting everything about CommonJS, ES Modules in depth: take a look [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/esm).